# Backbone/Marionette: Adding view events to a dynamically added view for a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

I've got a Marionette layout and for demo purposes the html looks like:

```
<header id="header-region" class="page-title"></header>
<section id="template-content" class="full-section">
  <div id="error-messages" class="fade main-section"><!-- errors --></div>
  <div id="content-region"> </div>
</section>
```

Its layout view's regions are:

```
regions: {
  header:  "#header-region",
  content: "#content-region"
}
```

Up until now, I've had any given page's modal html inside the page's template html which would be contained in the `content` region.

I have an idea to now create a separate region for modals to be shown in. 
Changing things to look like this:

Template:

```
<section id="template-content" class="full-section">
  <div id="error-messages" class="fade main-section"><!-- errors --></div>
  <div id="content-region"> </div>
  <div id="modal-region"></div>
</section>
```

And the region:

```
regions: {
  header:  "#header-region",
  content: "#content-region",
  modal: "#modal-region"
}
```

So I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
// Controller
define([], function(){
    initialize: function(){},
    showHeaderView: function(){
       this.HeaderView = new HeaderView();
       this.layout.header.show(this.HeaderView);
    },
    showContentView: function(){
      // this.BodyView's template used to contain the modal html
      this.BodyView = new BodyView();
      this.layout.content.show(this.BodyView);
    },
    showModalView: function(){
      this.ModalView = new ModalView();
      this.layout.modal.show(this.ModalView);
    }
});
```

This works and renders the modal properly but the modal's events are lost because they were originally set by this.BodyView.

The modal has a checkbox that on `change` runs a function that is on this.BodyView but I want to bind the events for this.ModalView from this.BodyView.

How can I accomplish that? I've tried making this.ModalView's el the same as this.BodyView's but that breaks things. I've tried to use `delegateEvents` as well but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This screencast does exactly what you want: http://www.backbonerails.com/screencasts/building-dialogs-with-custom-regions

Code is here: https://github.com/brian-mann/sc01-dialogs

Comment: Thanks, David. I actually tried another route at first to see if I could get it to work and its near complete. 

Basically I created view methods dynamically on the ModalView so that when a view event is triggered from the ModalView, it would call the same function that existed on the BodyView. This works. My only issue is that since the ModalView is created after the page is rendered, the `ui` object is no longer functioning properly so my functions that call `view.ui.whatever` are breaking. I tried using `bindUIElements` but that didn't work. How can I get the `ui` object to rebind?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the HeaderView as ItemView(or CollectionView/CompositeView) in it, you can instantiate it with passing arguments like

```
new HeaderView({events:{
"click .x" : function(){} // your function in-line or reference
});
```

So same applies to ModalView.